# Joomla is not install in windows 7?

Tags: joomla2.5

i am installing joomla 2.5 in my computer in 4th step after filling all the information like username, password and database name when i click on next button the process is going continue its not going 5th step.i am using wamp server

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the database that you entered does not exist. So Joomla may be taking to time to create the database and associated tables. Create a database for joomla and try again.

Hope my suggestion help. Thank you :-)

Comment: How you long have you been waiting, to get it installed?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that all the services of wamp has been started.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem while installing Joomla over WAMP on windows 7.  I tried many ways, but didn't find a way out.  So what I essentially did was took off WAMP and installed AppServ.  But then also I had a small hickup, as the latest version of AppServ comes with PHP 6.x and had the same problem... So I installed AppServ 2.5.10 (REF: http://www.appservnetwork.com/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=46) and everything went fine.

Hope this helps...

Note: Can you please confirm which version of PHP are you using with WAMP.. I have read somewhere (but not 100% sure) that latest version of PHP supports only MySQLi database type and not MySQL anymore (regarding step 4 of joomla installation)

Comment: 5.4.16 VERSION OF PHP

Comment: Is it possible for you to check your PHP error log to see some information is available there regarding this?